# grafana: singlestat percentages for time selected

Tags: grafana

I am using:

- Grafana - 4.4.3
- Graphite - 0.9.12

my goal is to have 3 singlestats:

1. visitors
2. registrations
3. percentage of visitors becoming registrations.

for selected timeframe I have 2 singlestats:

1. site visitors
   `sumSeries(stats.counters.$server.visitors.count)`
2. site registrations
   `sumSeries(stats.counters.$server.registrations.count)`

both works great, displays 1 number respectively and correct.

Now I want to add 3rd singlestat that should be the percentage of registrations for that timeframe
basically something like this:

```
A: sumSeries(stats.counters.$server.visitors.count)
B: asPercent(sumSeries(stats.counters.$server.registrations.count), #A)
```

to see the values... singlestats show:

1. visitors: 24131
2. registrations: 700

3: seleted

`delta`: 1629.75%

`avg`: 7.02%

`current`: 4.35%

`total`: 3232.60%

so all of them are wrong...

so it seems that it is not getting sum of all from `A` and sum of all `B` before doing `asPecent`?

what I need is to have a direct calculation on totals for A and B and from those 2 numbers get 1 number...
`700/24131*100=2.90`

so 3rd singlestat should display `2.90%`.

it seems tried all the variations possible, am I missing something obvious here?